# How can I update a cell into worksheet without create new worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I want to update a cell inside my worksheet but the only code I found online is how to create a new one.

How can I update a cell in the worksheet (see ????)?

```cs
public static void InsertText(string docName, string text)
{
    // Open the document for editing.
    using SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true);
    // Get the SharedStringTablePart. If it does not exist, create a new one.
    SharedStringTablePart shareStringPart;

    if (spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().Count() > 0)
    {
        shareStringPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().First();
    }
    else
    {
        shareStringPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<SharedStringTablePart>();
    }

    // Insert the text into the SharedStringTablePart.
    int index = InsertSharedStringItem(text, shareStringPart);

    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = ????
    
    Cell cell = InsertCellInWorksheet("A", 1, worksheetPart);
    
    // Set the value of cell A1.
    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(index.ToString());
    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.SharedString);

    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
```

Comment: The standard way to do this is to create a new one, delete the old one and rename the new one to match the old one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how can i do it? Can you explain me with an example of code?

Comment: You want to update the value of the cell?

Comment: yeah, i want to change the value (ex. from 0 to 135 or from 4 to 2 or from blank to "text")

Comment: please provide the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below allows you to update the cell.

```
public class UpdateExcelCell
    {    
        public void UpdateCell(string docName, string text,uint rowIndex, string columnName)
        {
            // Open the document for editing.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet =SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
            {
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, "Sheet1");

                if (worksheetPart != null)
                {
                    Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, columnName, rowIndex);

                    cell.CellValue = new CellValue(text);
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);

                    // Save the worksheet.
                    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
                }
            }

        }

        private static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName)
        {
            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

            if (sheets.Count() == 0)
            {
                // The specified worksheet does not exist.
                return null;
            }

            string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
            return worksheetPart;

        }

        // Given a worksheet, a column name, and a row index, 
        // gets the cell at the specified column and 
        private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, uint rowIndex)
        {
            Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

            if (row == null)
                return null;

            return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName + rowIndex, true) == 0).First();
        }


        // Given a worksheet and a row index, return the row.
        private static Row GetRow(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex)
        {
            return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
        }
    }
```

You call it as follows:

```
UpdateExcelCell xl = new UpdateExcelCell();
xl.UpdateCell(@"C:\Book1.xlsx","cell has been changed",1,"A");
```

Comment: I have already found that solution online but it doesn't work. It gives me .Name error ('OpenXmlElement' does not contain a definition of 'Name' and no accessible extension method 'Name' was found that takes a first argument of type 'OpenXmlElement'. Probably missing a using directive or reference to 'assembly.) and GetFirstChild (Cannot infer type arguments for method' OpenXmlElement.GetFirstChild <T> () 'from usage. Try specifying type arguments explicitly) and EnumValue (Using the generic type type 'EnumValue <T>' requires arguments of type 1). How can I solve?

Comment: you have to specify above what have your already tried and what errors you have received. People are not going to do the work for you.

Comment: the code above works. You will just have to look about the error when opening the file after update.

Comment: Ok, good. After your editing it works. Thanks a lot. However I did not ask to solve it but to correct the errors that presented themselves to me haha

Comment: your code is incomplete. No one will look into something which has missing parts.